# Embedded with ManyToMany

Tags: jpa, datanucleus

Is it possible to have something like this:

```
@Entity class A {
    @Embedded B b;
}
@Embeddable class B {
    @ManyToMany Collection<C> collectionOfC;
}
@Entity class C {}
```

I tried and I got

> org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.exceptions.NoTableManagedException: Persistent class "B" has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.

I'm using `org.datanucleus:datanucleus-accessplatform-jpa-rdbms:4.1.1`.

Comment: Depends on your provider and JPA version https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Relationships  There is no mention of Datanucleus support though.

Comment: Depends on provider, and not portable. A problem here is that the "B" has no _id_ and so the join table for the collection would have no clear _id_ to use; it could use the owning "A" but then there may be other parts of the object model with B's owned by other object types. IIRC I've used single-valued relations from Embeddables with DataNucleus; but fairly certain I've never tried multi-valued relations. Looking at some documentation (those Wikibooks pages) written primarily by EclipseLink authors isn't really a place to find out whether your implementation supports something though.